# Shinui Makom Summary Table

Tags: halacha, blessing, hefsek-interruption, trees

Is there available online a summary table, or better yet, a decision tree, that presents the conditional logic of the somewhat complicated laws of *hesech hada'ath*/*shinui makom* (diverted attention, e.g. by changing one's place), when one is required to make a new blessing over a food item or meal because the original blessing no longer applies?

For example, it should cover the consensus rulings regarding going outdoors vs. to a different room, for a bread meal, *mezonos* (non-bread grain), other foods, with and without leaving people behind.  Ideally, it would include disputing views of major authorities, as well as other types of *hesech hada'ath* / *hefsek* (interruption) that would also require a new blessing.

Comment: The Avnei Yashfei has many such tables ,not sure if he did for change of location